# run rspec multiple times with argument

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm developing a converter, and I use the rspec to check the values which were converted are correct. In order to check the value, I need to load the converted file (written in JSON). So I readied a method to load converted files in `spec_helper.rb`. I call this method in each spec file with `:before` hooks (But it's not the essence of this question).

Then, I want to run the same rspec tests for multiple converted results. This is a just image.

```
file_names = [ 'file1', 'file2', 'file3' ] # OR use Dir.glob to get some file paths
file_names.each do |file|
  all_rspec_tests( file )
end
```

Please tell me the best practice where I iterate some file names. I tried a few patterns.

1) In Rakefile, We can't pass the variable with RakeTask. Then I used ENV (Environment variable), like this: [how to pass command-line parameter to Rspec script?](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1537620)
It didn't work expectedly. In particular, a RakeTast does not run as sequential (looks like running on the other thread), so each test didn't run correctly.

2) Make a module and extend RSpec with it like this:
[Run the same spec multiple times w/ different filters](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/470)
But It's a pattern for using JavaScript. And I don't know this method will be success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use:

```
system "rspec \"%s\" --format CustomFormatter --require environment" % file
```

But you need a folder 'spec' with two files custom_formatter.rb and environment.rb

custom_formatter.rb:

```
require "rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter"
require 'yaml'
class CustomFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::BaseTextFormatter
  def initialize(output)
    super(output)
  end
  def example_started proxy
  end
  def example_passed proxy
    p "\tPassed: " + proxy.description
  end
  def example_failed proxy
  end
  def example_group_started group
  end
  def example_group_finished group
  end
end
```

environment.rb:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/wait"
require "test/unit"
require 'system/report_html_template'
require "system/logger"
require "system/report"
require "rspec"

include Selenium
include Watir

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fail_fast = true
    config.before(:all) do
    end
    config.after(:all) do
    end
end
```